# Error removing Microsoft.Net Framework 4

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework

I am having issues removing Microsoft.Net. I recently upgraded to Windows 8 Pro from Windows 7 and by doing so a few of my files have been changed and/or needed upgrading. I currently have Microsoft.NET 4 Framework installed and I'm trying to remove it. Every time I go to uninstall, I get an error saying "Already apart of operating System, but is currently turned off. You must turn it on via Control Panel". I went to my Control Panel to turn it on, which can be shown:

[image]

This is really frustrating because I have no idea how to fix this issue, and I do not have my Windows 7 disk anymore to downgrade. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Comment: If you upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 then you don't have .NET Framework 4.0 installed you have .NET Framework 4.5 installed since its an in-place replacement.  So I am going go ahead and remove the `Windows 7` tag.  The .NET Framework 4.5 **CANNOT** be removed if your running Windows 8.  Just like you CANNOT remove .NET 3.5 if your running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn it on fully, the fact it's a square box suggests it's only partly on. Expand the tree to turn on all/turn off all.